# How to execute same command on all computers in domain?

Tags: windows, command

i want to execute `winrm qc`command on all computers in domain from one of the computer in domain.
all computers in domain are of windows OS.
suggest best way to do this.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you're asking on SO, I'm going to assume that you want to know about how to develop code to do this.

In this case, you basically have two separate pieces to look at:

1. Find the computers in the domain
2. Run the code on each

There are a couple of ways to find computers, but probably the simplest is to use [`NetServerEnum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370623.aspx). Despite the name, it can enumerate workstations as well as servers (though you can restrict it to servers, or even more specific subsets, such as machines running SQL Server, print servers, etc.)

To run the code on each, you probably want to use the [Task Scheduler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any alternate option for Task Scheduler because i dont want to run this command again and again. also command "winrm qc" is for configuring windows remote management service.it is executed through command prompt.

Comment: @sagar: You can use the task scheduler to run a task only once. It just lets you execute things remotely. Running through the command prompt isn't a problem, but if you're planning to run it interactively, you'll need to use something like remote desktop, which adds a lot more complexity.